# Evitar dados em branco vindos do input

Tags: python, lista

Tenho uma lista vazia que será alimentada por `inputs`.

No caso, como faço para percorrer a lista e verificar se algum dado foi inputado em branco e tratá-lo para preencher novamente?

Exemplo:

```
lista = []

variavel_1 = lista.insert(0,input("Digite o numero: "))
variavel_2 = lista.insert(1,input("Digite o segundo numero: "))
```

Resultado: `lista = ['1',' ']`

Queria fazer de uma forma que não fosse tratada por `if`'s na `input` ou `while`. 
Teria como? Ou existe uma função do Python que chama na `input` para não entrar com dados em branco?

Comment: Essa parte aqui: "fazer de uma forma que não fosse tratada por ifs na input" isso significa o que? Que a verificação deva ser feita apenas após toda lista preenchida?

Comment: Não sei se seria o mais certo.. Mas não queria tratar com ifs na input.

Comment: Faça as verificações logo na entrada como o @FilipeMachado sugeriu.

Comment: Beleza! Valeu..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ao contrário do que algumas respostas afirmaram, você não deveria remover itens da lista dentro do mesmo *loop* que itera sobre ela. Pode até funcionar em alguns casos, mas em outros não vai, conforme podemos ver a seguir.

Considere o caso abaixo, que remove os elementos que são strings vazias:

```
lista = [ '', '', '', 'x' ]
for x in lista:
    if x == '': # se for string vazia, remove
        lista.remove(x)

# deveria sobrar só o 'x', mas...    
print(lista) # ['', 'x']
```

Este código imprime:

```
['', 'x']
```

Um dos elementos que deveria ser removido não foi.

---

## Por que isso acontece?

Para entender melhor o que aconteceu, vamos usar uma outra lista:

```
lista = [ '1', '2', '3', 'x' ]
for x in lista:
    if x.isdigit(): # se for um dígito, remove
        lista.remove(x)

print(lista) # ['2', 'x']
```

Agora estou usando [`isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) para remover as strings que contém apenas dígitos. Apesar disso, o resultado é a lista `['2', 'x']`.

Isso acontece porque na primeira iteração do `for`, ele pega o primeiro elemento da lista (a string `'1'`). Como [`isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) retorna `True` para esta string, ele entra no `if` e o `'1'` é removido da lista.

Na segunda iteração do `for`, ele pega o segundo elemento da lista. Mas como o `'1'` já foi removido, o segundo elemento agora é a string `'3'` (ou seja, a string `'2'`, que deveria ter sido removida, foi pulada). Por isso o `'2'` ainda aparece no resultado final.

De maneira mais detalhada:

- primeira iteração do `for`, a lista está assim:

```
[ '1', '2', '3', 'x' ]
```

- é verificado o primeiro elemento da lista (`'1'`), e como `isdigit()` retorna `True`, este é removido. Ou seja, agora a lista está assim:

```
[ '2', '3', 'x' ]
```

- na segunda iteração do `for`, ele pega o segundo elemento, que é o `'3'`, e `isdigit()` também retorna `True`, então este é removido. Agora a lista está assim:

```
[ '2', 'x' ]
```

- na terceira iteração do `for`, ele tenta pegar o terceiro elemento, mas como a lista só tem 2 elementos, o *loop* se encerra.

Você pode se certificar de que isso acontece colocando um `print` no `for`:

```
lista = [ '1', '2', '3', 'x' ]
for x in lista:
    print('testando', x)
    if x.isdigit():
        print('removendo', x)
        lista.remove(x)
```

A saída é:

```
testando 1
removendo 1
testando 3
removendo 3
```

Como pode ver, o `'2'` foi "pulado". E o `'x'` nem sequer foi verificado (se ele também fosse uma string que contém somente dígitos, ou seja, algo que deveria ser removido, ela também não seria removida).

---

## Então como eu faço?

Se você quer eliminar alguns elementos da lista seguindo determinado critério, você pode criar outra lista contendo somente os elementos que precisa. Ex:

```
lista = [ '', '', '', 'x' ]
# manter apenas os elementos que não forem vazios
lista = [ x for x in lista if x != '' ]
print(lista) # ['x']
```

Eu usei a sintaxe de [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions), para obter os elementos que não são strings vazias. E no caso, eu atribuí para a mesma lista, mas você poderia criar outra se quisesse:

```
lista = [ '', '', '', 'x' ]
# manter apenas os elementos que não forem vazios
outra_lista = [ x for x in lista if x != '' ]
```

Dessa forma não ocorre o problema citado no início, de pular indevidamente alguns elementos.

Outra alternativa é usar o [módulo `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), e sua função [`filterfalse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse):

```
from itertools import filterfalse

lista = [ '', '', '', 'x' ]

lista = list(filterfalse(lambda s: s == '', lista))
print(lista) # ['x']
```

`filterfalse` considera os elementos para os quais a condição é falsa. No caso, eu usei como condição um *lambda* que verifica se a string é vazia, então ele vai retornar os elementos que não são vazios.

---

#### Sobre as outras dúvidas:

> *como faço para percorrer a lista e verificar se algum dado foi inputado em branco e tratá-lo para preencher novamente?*

Neste caso você poderia fazer algo assim:

```
lista = [ '', '', '', 'x' ]
for i, _ in enumerate(lista):
    while lista[i] == '':
        lista[i] = input('digite um número:')
```

O `while` serve para pedir que o usuário digite algo, e enquanto esse algo for a string vazia, ele pede que digite novamente. Se o item não for vazio, nem entra no `while` e o item não é modificado.

---

> *Queria fazer de uma forma que não fosse tratada por `if`'s na `input` ou `while`. Teria como? Ou existe uma função do Python que chama na `input` para não entrar com dados em branco?*

Por que não quer usar `if` ou `while`? São duas das estruturas mais básicas da programação, e não há problema nenhum em usá-las.

No caso do `input`, basta fazer um *loop* pedindo que se digite a informação, até que ela seja o que você quer:

```
while True:
    s = input('digite o número: ')
    if s != '':
        break
```

Se a string `s` for vazia, ele continua no `while`, pedindo que digite novamente. Se não for vazia, entra no `if` e o `break` interrompe o *loop*.

Se bem que no seu caso você está pedindo que digite um número, então por que não validar logo se é um número mesmo?

```
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('digite o número: '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Não foi digitado um número')
```

Se não for digitado um número, [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) lançará um [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) e cairá no bloco `except` (que por sua vez informa que não foi digitado um número), e o `while` prossegue, pedindo ao usuário que digite novamente. Se a conversão para número der certo, o código cai no `break`, que interrompe o *loop*.

No caso, `int()` só aceita números inteiros. Mas se quiser números com casas decimais, basta trocar para [`float()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float).

Assim você garante logo no início que sua lista só terá valores válidos, e nem precisa tratá-los depois.

Mais uma coisa: se quer adicionar valores no final da lista, use `append` em vez de `insert`. Basta fazer `lista.append(valor)`, que o valor é inserido no final da lista (veja mais detalhes na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)).
Outro detalhe é que [`lista.insert` retorna `None`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1516889), então não faz sentido atribuir o retorno de `insert` em uma variável, como você fez em `variavel_1` e `variavel_2`.

---

#### Sobre "dados em branco"

Não ficou muito claro o que você considera um "dado em branco". Se for somente um espaço, então tudo bem usar o que [uma das respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/435087/112052) sugeriu (comparar com `' '` - repare que há um espaço entre as aspas). Nos meus exemplos eu usei uma string vazia (`''`), que é o que `input` retorna quando só é digitado um <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Ambos são válidos, dependendo do que você precisa.

Mas e se forem digitados vários espaços (ex: `'     '`), você também considera que é um "dado em branco"? Caso seja, uma forma de comparar seria:

```
# s é a string que estou verificando se é "em branco"
if s.isspace() or s == '':
    # em branco (ou vazio)
```

Eu usei o [método `isspace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace) que verifica se a string só tem espaços - lembrando que a definição de "espaço" que ele usa é "*um caractere que possui a categoria Unicode [Zs ("Separator, space")](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/index.htm), ou a [classe bidirecional](https://unicode.org/reports/tr9/) é WS, B ou S.*" ([veja aqui](https://ideone.com/BuzcMA) a lista completa desses caracteres).

Mas `isspace()` exige que haja pelo menos um caractere na string, então eu também testo se a string é vazia. Outra forma de fazer é eliminar os espaços do início e fim da string (usando [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)) e verificar se o que sobra é vazio:

```
if s.strip() == '':
    # s é "em branco"
```

Comment: Cara, excelente sua explicação! Muito obrigado... Vou seguir dessa forma.

Answer (score 2):

Parece que você esqueceu de fechar parênteses ao final de cada atribuição de variável, mas acho que não é o que vem ao caso.

Sinceramente, não vejo muitas alternativas em percorrer a lista e remover itens a não ser usando um `if`.

Caso ajude, uma solução simples pode ser:

```
lista = []

variavel_1 = lista.insert(0,input("Digite o numero: "))
variavel_2 = lista.insert(1,input("Digite o segundo numero: "))
for item in lista:
    if item == ' ':
        lista.remove(' ')

print(lista)
```

Comment: Verdade! Corrigido. Caso não exista outra forma, vou tentar assim mesmo.

Comment: Deu certo! Valeu..

Comment: @M4estri Só um detalhe: remover itens da lista dentro do `for` nem sempre vai funcionar, eu coloquei um exemplo na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/435747/112052)

Answer (score 1):

Sem usar `while` ou `if`, o melhor que dá para fazer de forma curta seria forçar a tipagem do input. Se só irá receber números, usar o `int()` ou `float()` como wrap do `input()` faz retornar um erro como abaixo

```
variavel_1 = lista.insert(0,float(input("Digite o numero: ")))
variavel_2 = lista.insert(1,float(input("Digite o segundo numero: ")))

Digite o numero: 1
Digite o segundo numero:
```

--//--

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-13b4d3494daf> in <module>
      2 
      3 variavel_1 = lista.insert(0,int(input("Digite o numero: ")))
----> 4 variavel_2 = lista.insert(1,int(input("Digite o segundo numero: ")))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Se você não quer o erro ocorrendo, você pode usar a função `try:`

```
try:
    variavel_1 = lista.insert(0,float(input("Digite o numero: ")))
    variavel_2 = lista.insert(1,float(input("Digite o segundo numero: ")))
except Exception as e:
    #Insira a aqui a tua tratativa para o erro
    print("Insira um número válido!")

Digite o numero: 
Insira um número válido!
```

No mais, teria que usar um `if` em um loop `for` ou `while` para verificar.

Answer (score 0):

Se quer restringir uma determinada entrada precisa criar uma condição. Uma forma de resolver esse problema é usando `try` e `except`.

A ideia seria: o programa vai tentar fazer uma ação e se ele n conseguir vai ir por outro caminho.

Exemplo:

```
lista = []

[lista.append(input('Digite o {}º número: ' .format(x+1))) for x in range (3)]

for x in lista:
    try: float(x)
    except: lista.remove(x)


# Outra forma:
# for x in lista:
#     try: 
#         float(x)
#     except: 
#         lista.remove(x)
```

Assim, tudo que estiver no `try` ele vai tentar fazer, se em algum momento der erro no código ele vai para o `except` fazendo alguma outra ação (como por exemplo alguma mensagem de erro)

Comment: Gui Reis. Evite colocar comprimentos, assinatura e abreviação léxicas.

Answer (score 0):

Tirando o pré-conceito contra os whiles... :-D

```
lista = []
x = 1
while x < 3:
    v = input(f"Digite o {x}º número: ")
    try:
        lista.append(float(v))
        x += 1
    except ValueError:
        print("Valor inválido, redigite.")

print(lista)
```

Que resulta em:

```
Digite o 1º número: 9
Digite o 2º número: r
Valor inválido, redigite.
Digite o 2º número:
Valor inválido, redigite.
Digite o 2º número: 2
[9.0, 2.0]
```

Imaginando que você já tem a lista, mas quer fazer uma validação e completar caso necessário:

```
def float_ou_nada(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except ValueError:
        return None

# Lista inicial, assumindo que esta já tenha sido lida anteiormente
lista = [1, "x", ""]
# Limpa a lista
lista = [v for v in lista if float_ou_nada(v) is not None]
# Testa se a lista tem o tamanho desejado, pegunda os elementos que faltam
while len(lista) < 2:
    v = input(f"Digite o {len(lista)+1}º número: ")
    try:
        lista.append(float(v))
    except ValueError:
        print("Valor inválido, redigite.")
print(lista)
```

que resulta em:

```
Digite o 2º número: o
Valor inválido, redigite.
Digite o 2º número:
Valor inválido, redigite.
Digite o 2º número: 9
[1, 9.0]
```

Você também pode trocar float por int se o que queres são números inteiros.