# Remover as letras minúsculas de uma lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Eu estava tentando fazer um programa que conseguisse identificar se uma letra está em upper case ou em lower case em uma lista, de forma que ela excluísse as letras minúsculas.

```
frase = ("A B C D e f g h")
new = list ((frase).split())

for i in new :
    if i == i.lower() :
        new.remove(i)
    
print (new)
```

O problema é que este código retorna `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'f', 'h']` e não `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']` como era planejado. Gostaria de saber o porquê disso e como consertar.

Comment: [Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/mzamztht-solkarped) uma forma alternativa de resolver o seu problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/438696/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/435747/112052), remover itens de uma lista ao mesmo tempo em que itera sobre ela pode trazer resultados inesperados.

Modificando um pouco seu código, podemos entender o que acontece:

```
frase = ("A B C D e f g h")
new = list((frase).split())

for index, i in enumerate(new):
    print(new)
    print('verificando', index, i)
    if i == i.lower():
        print('removendo', i)
        new.remove(i)
```

A saída é:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
verificando 0 A
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
verificando 1 B
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
verificando 2 C
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
verificando 3 D
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
verificando 4 e
removendo e
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'f', 'g', 'h']
verificando 5 g
removendo g
```

Ou seja, ao chegar no índice 4 (cujo elemento é `'e'`), este é removido, e a lista passa a ser `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'f', 'g', 'h']`.

Na próxima iteração, pega-se o elemento que está no índice 5, que é o "g". Repare que o "f" foi pulado, pois como o "e" foi removido, o "f" está no índice 4.

E depois que o "g" é removido, a lista passa a ser `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'f', 'h']`. Na próxima iteração pegaria-se o índice 6, mas agora a lista não tem mais este índice e o *loop* se encerra.

---

Para resolver isso, você não precisa criar a lista `new` com todas as letras, só para depois remover algumas. Basta criar uma lista vazia e só adicionar os elementos que você quer. Além disso, se só quer manter as letras maiúsculas, use [`isupper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper) para verificar se é maiúscula:

```
frase = "A B C D e f g h"
new = []
for i in frase.split():
    if i.isupper():
        new.append(i)
```

Ou use uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](/q/192343/112052):

```
frase = "A B C D e f g h"
new = [ i for i in frase.split() if i.isupper() ]
```

---

Só um detalhe: a pergunta diz que quer "*excluir as letras minúsculas*". Ou seja, números e sinais de pontuação, entre outros caracteres que não são letras, devem ser mantidos? Afinal, se eu só excluir as letras minúsculas, os números e demais caracteres deveriam se manter.

Neste caso, você poderia mudar a condição para `if not i.islower()` (não é minúscula). Veja como faz diferença:

```
frase = "A B C D e f g h 1 2 3 ! @"

# remove as minúsculas (números e outros caracteres se mantém)
new = [ i for i in frase.split() if not i.islower() ]
print(new) # ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '1', '2', '3', '!', '@']

# só mantém as letras maiúsculas (qualquer outra coisa não é considerada)
new = [ i for i in frase.split() if i.isupper() ]
print(new) # ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Claro que se a frase só tiver letras, aí tanto faz usar um outro, **exceto** se tiver letras de alguns alfabetos que não são maiúsculas nem minúsculas. Em japonês, por exemplo, não existe este conceito, então as letras não são nem maiúsculas nem minúsculas (tanto `isupper()` quanto `islower()` retornam `False`). E existem também as letras que são [*title case*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31771075), como o `ǅ` ([LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D WITH SMALL LETTER Z WITH CARON](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/01c5/index.htm)) (que também não são *upper* nem *lower case*):

```
for s in ['親', 'ǅ']:
    print(s.isupper(), s.islower()) # False False para ambos
```

Sendo assim, estas letras também farão diferença, dependendo do método escolhido:

```
# contém letras de outros alfabetos que não são maiúsculas nem minúsculas
frase = "A B C D e f 親 ǅ"

# remove as minúsculas
new = [ i for i in frase.split() if not i.islower() ]
print(new) # ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '親', 'ǅ']

# só mantém as letras maiúsculas (qualquer outra coisa não é considerada)
new = [ i for i in frase.split() if i.isupper() ]
print(new) # ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas, só por curiosidade, essa letra em japonês tem algum significado ?

Comment: @Smaug Na verdade peguei um caractere qualquer aleatoriamente, nenhum significado especial...

Comment: Posso estar dizendo bobagem, pois não leio kanji , mas o caractere é oya(oi-á) significa pai e também é radical para relações de parentesco por parte de pai.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Fui pesquisar e [parece que o significado é esse mesmo](https://www.joyokanji.com/character-home-page-temp/%E8%A6%AA) (mas como eu já disse, fiz uma pesquisa aleatória por textos em japonês e peguei a primeira frase que apareceu, não foi uma tentativa de deixar um "easter egg" nem nada do tipo). Já faz muito tempo que estudei japonês (e esqueci quase tudo), mas lembro que cada kanji tem várias pronúncias diferentes, dependendo do contexto (nesse caso, "oyá" é uma delas, mas [tem muitas outras](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%A6%AA#Readings) - "shin", "shita", "mizuka", etc)

Answer (score 3):

Você não pode remover elementos de uma coleção com um `for` porque invalida o iterador. Ou tem que fazer isso manualmente, o que é arriscado se não souber fazer direito ou deve criar uma nova lista com os itens que devem continuar na lista:

```
frase = "A B C D e f g h".split()
novo = []
for i in frase:
    if i.isupper():
        novo.append(i)
print(novo)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/XeHRmK). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xziarqvj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/FilterList2.py).

Answer (score 1):

Espero que auxilie, eu poderia melhorar mas da para resolver essa questão.

def lista(frase):

```
new =[]

for i in frase :
    if i !=i.lower() :
        print('adicionando:{}'.format(i))
        new.append(i)
    
    
    
print (new)
```

if **name** == "**main**":

```
  frase = ("A B C D e f g h")
  lista(frase)
```