# Nesse programa, queria que incluísse na lista final, os números pares da primeira lista e os ímpares da segunda, por que isso não ocorre?(python)

Tags: python, lista

*Na lista final, acabam aparecendo números que não eram supostos por estar ali, 
por exemplo o 103, que é um número ímpar da primeira lista.

```
lista_1 = [10,24,50,103,30,12]                             
lista_2 = [13, 16, 39, 14, 107, 35]                         
for elementos in lista_1:                                 
  if elementos % 2 == 0:                                  
    lista_1.remove(elementos)                                
for unidades in lista_2:                                     
  if unidades % 2 != 0:                                      
    lista_2.remove(unidades)                                 
lista_final = lista_1 + lista_2                              
print(lista_final)
```

O código resultou em                                         
[24, 103, 12, 16, 14, 35]

Comment: Se você quer os elementos pares da `lista_1`, por que está usando o `remove` para removê-los da lista? Recomendo você fazer o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878) para descrever o seu código e entender o que realmente fez.

Comment: Não remova itens de uma lista no mesmo loop que itera nela: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/466768/112052

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que está acontecendo na sua questão é que você está **removendo**, justamente os elementos que deseja exibir.

Quando você faz...

```
for elementos in lista_1:                                 
  if elementos % 2 == 0:                                  
    lista_1.remove(elementos)
```

... na realidade você está verificando se `elementos % 2 == 0` é par e, se for, você remove ele da  lista. Por isso nunca vai da certo. O correto seria você não remove-lo.

Uma das formas corretas para se resolver esta questão é:

```
lista_1 = [10, 24, 50, 103, 30, 12]
lista_2 = [13, 16, 39, 14, 107, 35]
lista_final = list()
for elementos in lista_1:
    if elementos % 2 == 0:
        lista_final.append(elementos)
for unidades in lista_2:
    if unidades % 2 != 0:
        lista_final.append(unidades)
lista_final.sort()
print(lista_final)
print()
```

Observe que o algoritmo verifica se `elementos % 2 == 0` se é par e, se for, adiciona na `lista_final`. Depois o algoritmo verifica se `unidades % 2 != 0` se é ímpar e, se for, adiciona também na `lista_final`.

Em seguida, ordena a lista e, em seguida, exibe a `lista_final` contendo os números pares da `lista_1` e os números ímpares da `lista_2`.

Comment: Obrigado mano, saquei qual foi meu erro