# Porque meu código está "engolindo" string em uma lista?

Tags: python, lista

```
letras = ["A", "B", "C", "B"]
vogais = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

for letra in letras:
    if letra.lower() in vogais:
        print(letra.upper())
        letras.remove(letra)
    elif letra.lower() not in vogais:
        print(letra)
```

Porque meu código não está lendo o primeiro "B" que está na lista de letras?

Comment: Deve está com o mesmo valor nos dois  "B" veja ai.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/438696/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/435747/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/466780/112052), remover elementos de uma lista no mesmo *loop* que itera sobre ela pode causar esses problemas. Para ilustrar melhor, vamos modificar um pouco o *loop*:

```
letras = ["A", "B", "C", "B"]
for indice, letra in enumerate(letras):
    print(f' antes: {indice}={letra} - lista={letras}')
    letras.remove(letra)
    print(f'depois: {indice}={letra} - lista={letras}')
```

Eu uso [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) para iterar pelos índices e os respectivos elementos ao mesmo tempo. A saída é:

```
 antes: 0=A - lista=['A', 'B', 'C', 'B']
depois: 0=A - lista=['B', 'C', 'B']
 antes: 1=C - lista=['B', 'C', 'B']
depois: 1=C - lista=['B', 'B']
```

Ou seja, na primeira iteração (quando o índice é 0), a `letra` corresponde ao primeiro elemento (índice zero), que é a letra "A". Depois de removê-la, a lista passa a ser `['B', 'C', 'B']`.

Na segunda iteração (quando o índice é 1), a `letra` corresponde ao segundo elemento da lista. Mas como a lista foi modificada e o "A" foi removido, o segundo elemento (que está no índice 1) é a letra "C". Portanto o primeiro "B" é pulado.

---

A [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) dá algumas alternativas para você evitar este problema e fazer o que quer. Ou você cria outra lista com os elementos que você quer (ou seja, tudo que não for vogal):

```
letras = ["A", "B", "C", "B"]
vogais = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
resultado = []
for letra in letras:
    if letra.lower() in vogais:
        print(letra.upper())
    else:
        print(letra)
        resultado.append(letra)

print(resultado)
```

Ou você itera sobre uma cópia da lista:

```
letras = ["A", "B", "C", "B"]
vogais = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
for letra in letras.copy(): # itero sobre uma cópia
    if letra.lower() in vogais:
        print(letra.upper())
        letras.remove(letra) # agora posso remover, pois não afeta a cópia
    else:
        print(letra)
```

Repare também que não precisa do `elif`. No `if` você vê se a letra está na lista de vogais. Se estiver, entra no `if`, e se chegou no `else`, é porque não está, então é redundante e desnecessário testar isso de novo.

Answer (score 0):

Que tal utilizar a exclusão por índice?

```py
letras = ["A", "B", "C", "E", "B"]
vogais = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
i = 0
while i < len(letras):
    if letras[i].lower() in vogais:
        del letras[i]
        # os próximos elementos terão índice reduzido em 1, não devendo-se inclementar i
    else:
        i+=1
print(letras)
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso está acontecendo porque na hora que você está dando ***letras.remove(letra)*** no seu código o tamanho da lista está sendo alterado e consequentemente o Index de todos os itens nela está diminuindo em 1.

Por exemplo:

- o item ***"A"*** de letras tem um ***Index 0*** antes da remoção e a primeira letra ***"B"*** tem o ***Index 1***.

> ["A", "B", "C", "B"] # respectivamente os Index são: 0, 1, 2, 3

- Assim que a letra ***"A"*** é removida o ***Index*** do ***"B"*** passa a ser ***0*** e como o loop já passou por ele o primeiro ***"B"*** não é lido porque sua lista ficou assim:

> ["B","C","B"] # respectivamente os Index são: 0, 1, 2
> Neste momento o for já passou do ***Index 0*** e vai seguir para o próximo até chegar no ***Index 2***

Segue abaixo uma solução simples sem mudar muito seu código:

- 1. Adicionando uma lista de letras para serem removidas e o append para ela também.

> No caso: ***removidos = [ ]*** e ***removidos.append(letra)***

```
letras = ["A", "B", "C", "B"] 
vogais = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

removidos = []

for letra in letras: 
    if letra.lower() in vogais:
        print(f'A letra "{letra}" será removida')
        removidos.append(letra) # Adicionando a letra na lista de remoção futura para não atrapalhar a leitura da lista atual

    elif letra.lower() not in vogais: # Você simplesmente pode usar um else aqui no lugar do elif caso não exista mais outra condição
        print(letra)
```

- 2. Removendo a letra sem atrapalhar na leitura da lista original:

> Usando um loop ***for*** para ler todos os itens dentro da lista de removidos e o ***letras.remove(letra_removida)***
> para retirar elas da lista original

```
for letra_removida in removidos:
    letras.remove(letra_removida) # Utilizando a lista de removidos para tirar as vogais depois do outro loop
```

3.1 Jeito de ver a lista inteira:

```
print(f"Lista sem vogais: {letras}") # Resultado
```

Seu ***resultado*** será:

- ***Lista sem vogais: ["B","C","B"]***

3.2 Ou um item por vez:

```
for letra in letras:
    print(letra)
```

Aqui seu ***resultado*** será:

- ***B***
- ***C***
- ***B***

Espero ter ajudado!