# Como remover todos os elementos de uma lista iguais a determinado valor

Tags: python, string, lista

Como remover todos os valores de uma lista que vão ter o mesmo significado por exemplo:

```
array = ['sim', 'sim', 'sim', 'sim', 'sim2', 'sim3', 'sim4']
```

Tem algum jeito de fazer um laço de repetição enquanto existir valores com 'sim', algo como `array.remove('sim')`, ou existe um método pra isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não faça como a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/474993/112052) (que foi apagada), porque remover elementos de uma lista no mesmo loop que itera sobre ela não funciona em todos os casos. Ex:

```
array = ['sim', 'sim', 'sim', 'sim', 'sim2', 'sim', 'sim3', 'sim4'] 
 
for i in array:
    array.remove('sim')
print(array) # ['sim2', 'sim', 'sim3', 'sim4']
```

Repare que nem todos os "sim" foram removidos. Esse comportamento é melhor explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/438696/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/435747/112052). Mas basicamente, podemos ver melhor o que acontece modificando um pouco o exemplo:

```py
array = ['sim', 'sim', 'sim', 'sim', 'sim2', 'sim', 'sim3', 'sim4'] 

for i, val in enumerate(array):
    array.remove('sim')
    print(f'posição {i} - array: {array}')
```

A saída é:

```
posição 0 - array: ['sim', 'sim', 'sim', 'sim2', 'sim', 'sim3', 'sim4']
posição 1 - array: ['sim', 'sim', 'sim2', 'sim', 'sim3', 'sim4']
posição 2 - array: ['sim', 'sim2', 'sim', 'sim3', 'sim4']
posição 3 - array: ['sim2', 'sim', 'sim3', 'sim4']
```

Na primeira iteração ele remove o primeiro "sim", na segunda iteração ele remove o segundo "sim" e assim por diante. Mas repare que após a quarta iteração, a lista só tem 4 elementos, e como o `for` já está na quarta iteração, o *loop* se encerra. Por isso ele não chega a remover o quinto "sim".

---

Enfim, a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) cita duas soluções pra evitar este problema. Ou você cria outra lista só com os valores que quer:

```
array = ['sim', 'sim', 'sim', 'sim', 'sim2', 'sim', 'sim3', 'sim4'] 
 
outra = []
for x in array:
    if x != 'sim':
         outra.append(x)

print(outra)
```

Ou você itera sobre uma cópia da lista:

```
array = ['sim', 'sim', 'sim', 'sim', 'sim2', 'sim', 'sim3', 'sim4'] 

for x in array.copy():
    if x == 'sim':
        array.remove(x)

print(array)
```

---

A primeira opção acima também pode ser feita  com [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](/q/192343/112052):

```py
array = ['sim', 'sim', 'sim', 'sim', 'sim2', 'sim', 'sim3', 'sim4'] 
 
outra = [ x for x in array if x != 'sim' ]
print(outra)
```

Ou então usando [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) para filtrar os elementos que devem ser removidos:

```py
array = ['sim', 'sim', 'sim', 'sim', 'sim2', 'sim', 'sim3', 'sim4'] 
 
outra = list(filter(lambda x: x != 'sim', array))
print(outra)
```

---

Por fim, você também pode começar a iteração do final, para que uma remoção não interfira na indexação dos demais elementos. As opções abaixo foram retiradas [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30114633) (lá tem outras também, para quem tiver curiosidade):

```py
array = ['sim', 'sim', 'sim', 'sim', 'sim2', 'sim', 'sim3', 'sim4'] 
for i in range(len(array) - 1, -1, -1):
    if 'sim' == array[i]:
        del array[i]
print(array)

# ou
array = ['sim', 'sim', 'sim', 'sim', 'sim2', 'sim', 'sim3', 'sim4'] 
for i, val in reversed(list(enumerate(array))):
    if 'sim' == val:
        del array[i]
print(array)
```

Answer (score 2):

Outra alternativa além da que o @Código de Senior disse é usar um laço while invés de um for, já que podemos nos deparar com listas das quais não sabemos quantos 'sim' haverão na lista o código fica assim:

```
array = ['sim', 'sim', 'sim', 'sim', 'sim2', 'sim3', 'sim4']

while 'sim' in array:
    array.remove('sim')

print(array)

['sim2', 'sim3', 'sim4']
```

Answer (score -2):

Estou tentando remover vários elementos de uma lista por um critério que eu estabeleci (com while), porém quando existem 2 elementos iguais juntos, somente e removido um elemento.

Exemplo:

Minha_Lista = list('leek is good for health')

for i, v in enumerate(Minha_Lista):
while v == 'e':
Minha_Lista.pop(i)
break

print(Minha_Lista)
Output:

['l', 'e', 'k', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'g', 'o', 'o', 'd', ' ', 'f', 'o', 'r', ' ', 'h', 'a', 'l', 't', 'h']

Obrigado