# Qual a lógica por trás do [i+1:] vasculhar todos os elementos dentro do vetor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, array

Não estou entendendo a lógica por trás disso:

```
for i, elemento in enumerate(lista):
    if elemento in lista[i+1:]:     # especificamente desta linha
        lista.remove(elemento)
```

Por que que todos os elementos do vetor são investigados? Quando i == 1, por que ele investiga se o elemento 0 também está na lista?

i+1: -> o seguimento do vetor partindo do (índice + 1).

Ou estou perdendo algo aqui? Comecei a aprender a pouco tempo.

Agradeço quaisquer respostas!

Abraços.

Comment: `[i+1:]` é um [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/), basicamente é uma forma de pegar um pedaço da lista. No caso, pega o pedaço que começa no índice `i + 1` e vai até o final. Dito isso, o que o código faz é: para cada elemento, veja se ele ocorre mais à frente e o remova. Não sei o motivo, nem se era essa intenção, mas enfim, remover elementos no mesmo loop que percorre a lista tem alguns problemas, mostrados [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/474996/112052).

Comment: O pior é que lendo teu comentário que clicou aqui: Ele não compara com o anterior, pois o anterior já foi verificado antes. É um for loop, então vai de elemento em elemento. Obrigado, meu querido!