# Como excluir elementos negativos de uma lista e adicionar-los em outra em python?

Tags: python

tentei com esse código mas não funciona com precisão

```
from random import randint

lista=10
X=list(range(lista))
R=[]

def gravarLista(X):
    for i in range(lista):
        X[i]=randint(-5, 5)
    print(X)
    for i in X:
        if i<0:
            X.pop(i)
            R.append(i)
    print(X)
    print(R)

gravarLista(X)
```

Answer (score 3):

Conforme explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/438696/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/435747/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/466780/112052), remover elementos de uma lista no mesmo loop que itera sobre ela pode causar problemas e não funciona em todos os casos (teste o código da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/475822/112052) - a [primeira versão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/c64791aa-c970-41ab-b1aa-0f5ac43736f9/view-source) - com uma lista como `[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, 1, 2, 3]` e veja que [ela não remove todos os negativos](https://ideone.com/hEaCjn)).

A [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) dá algumas alternativas para resolver isso. Uma delas é simplesmente criar outra lista com o que você precisa. No caso, podemos criar 2 listas, uma somente com os positivos e outra somente com os negativos:

```
def separar_negativos(numeros):
    negativos = []
    positivos = []
    for i in numeros:
        if i < 0:
            negativos.append(i)
        else:
            positivos.append(i)
    # retorna as 2 listas
    return positivos, negativos

from random import choices

tamanho = 10
numeros = choices(range(-5, 6), k=tamanho)
print(numeros)

positivos, negativos = separar_negativos(numeros)
print(positivos)
print(negativos)
```

Repare também que usei [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) para gerar a lista de números aleatórios, e usei `range(-5, 6)` (números entre -5 e 5, já que o valor final não é incluso - fiz assim para ficar compatível com `randint(-5, 5)`, que inclui o `5` entre os valores possíveis) - `choices` está disponível a partir do Python 3.6.

Outro detalhe é que eu passo a lista de números como argumento da função, assim ela fica mais "genérica" - da maneira que você fez, ela é criada dentro da função e só funciona para aquela lista criada internamente. Fazendo da maneira acima, não importa como a lista é criada, a função separa os números negativos e positivos independente disso.

Comment: `gostei` da resolução generalizada. Pois, isto mostra a verdadeira função do código - ser útil para diversas situações inerentes à respectiva lógica.

Comment: Se a pergunta resolveu o seu problema, marque ela como melhor resposta. Nós ficamos felizes em saber que ajudamos, mas não use comentários para agradecimentos ou supérfluos. Pode parecer rude, mas isso ajuda a manter a comunidade limpa.  Recomendo [essa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7785/como-debugar-programas-pequenos) leitura para que você consiga ser mais independente na hora de achar erros, e [essa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs) para entender melhor a comunidade e tentar evitar negativações.

Answer (score -1):

Seu programa apresenta 3 problemas principais:

1. Repare que você está preenchendo a lista `X` mais de uma vez. Isso é redundante.
2. Você está iterando sobre uma lista e alterando ela ao mesmo tempo, e isso é perigoso. Tome cuidado ao usar esse artifício.
3. Por fim, você usa a função `pop()` e passa como argumento um valor da lista, mas a função `pop` recebe como parâmetro um valor de `index`. Ou seja, ao fazer `lista.pop(5)` você não está apagando o valor `5`, você está apagando o item localizado no index 5. Para resolver esse problema, eu utilizei a função `lista.index(5)`. Essa função vai procurar o valor `5`, que foi passado como argumento, dentro da lista `lista` e retornar seu index. Assim:

```
from random import randint

lista = 10
X = []
R = []

def gravarLista(X):
    for i in range(lista):
        X.append(randint(-5, 5))
    print(X)

    for i in X:
        if i < 0:
            R.append(i)
    print(R)

    for j in R:
        if j in X:
            X.pop(X.index(j))
    print(X)


gravarLista(X)
```

Comment: Como vc mesmo disse, iterar por uma lista e alterá-la ao mesmo tempo não funciona: https://ideone.com/qMLM1L

Comment: Corrigi a resposta, grato pela observação. [Segue o código funcionando](https://ideone.com/Go2ala)