# Estudando listas

Tags: python, lista

Tenho duas listas, a primeira chamada de `cadastro` e a segunda chamada de `entrada`.

Eu retiro um item da lista `entrada` e depois quero retornar esse item caso ele esteja na lista `cadastro`, porem só consigo fazer isso com o primeiro item inserido.

Do contrário sempre retorna a segunda condição: "*O nome não se encontra na lista*".

```
cadastro = []
entrada = []
saida = []


def opc():
    cad = input('(1) Acessar cadastro - (2) Acessar entradas - (3) Registrar entrada - (4) Registrar saida:'
                ' - (5) Registrar retorno: \n -> ')

    if cad == '1':
        for c in cadastro:
            print(c)
        opc()

    elif cad == '2':
        for s in entrada:
            print(s)
        opc()

    elif cad == '3':
        entrar()

    elif cad == '4':
        sair()

    elif cad == '5':
        retorno()


def dados():
    nome = str(input('nome: '))

    cadastro.append({'nome': nome}),
    entrada.append({'nome': nome})


def entrar():
    dados()
    opc()


def sair():
    nome = str(input('Nome: '))

    for i in range(0, len(entrada)):
        user = entrada[i].get('nome')
        if user == nome:
            print(user)
            entrada.remove(entrada[i])
            opc()


def retorno():
    nome = str(input('Nome: '))

    for i in range(0, len(cadastro)):
        user = cadastro[i].get('nome')
        if nome == user:
            entrada.append(cadastro[i])
            print(entrada)
            opc()
        else:
            print('Nome não se encontra na lista.')
        opc()


opc()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, não chame a função dentro dela mesma, como você fez com `opc()`.

Apesar de "funcionar", não é o ideal. Isso porque cada vez que uma função é chamada, ela é "empilhada" (colocada na pilha de execução). E enquanto a função não retornar, ela fica lá ocupando espaço na pilha.

Ou seja, no seu programa, você chama `opc()`, que pode chamar ela mesma de novo, ou chamar uma das outras funções, que chama `opc()` de novo, que chama ela mesma ou uma das funções que chama `opc()` de novo, etc... Como nunca há um retorno dessas funções, elas ficam ocupando espaço na pilha. E se o programa rodar por muito tempo, pode acabar estourando a pilha ([veja aqui](https://ideone.com/JGnzoY) um exemplo, role até o final da página e veja o `RecursionError`).

> *<sup>Chamar uma função dentro dela mesma se chama "recursão", e é um recurso que [na maioria das vezes você não vai precisar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/112052).</sup>*

Enfim, se quiser que algo se repita várias vezes, use um *loop* simples. Pelo que entendi você quer algo assim:

```
cadastro = []
entrada = []
saida = []

def dados():
    nome = input('nome: ')
    cadastro.append(nome)
    entrada.append(nome)

def sair():
    nome = input('Nome: ')

    for i, user in enumerate(entrada):
        if user == nome:
            print(user)
            del entrada[i]
            break # se já encontrei, interrompe o for

def retorno():
    nome = input('Nome: ')
    for nome_cadastrado in cadastro:
        if nome == nome_cadastrado:
            entrada.append(nome_cadastrado)
            print(entrada)
            break # se já encontrou, interrompe o for
    else:
        print('Nome não se encontra na lista.')

while True: # loop infinito
    cad = input('(1) Acessar cadastro - (2) Acessar entradas - (3) Registrar entrada - (4) Registrar saida:'
                ' - (5) Registrar retorno: \n -> ')

    if cad == '1':
        for c in cadastro:
            print(c)
    elif cad == '2':
        for s in entrada:
            print(s)
    elif cad == '3':
        dados()
    elif cad == '4':
        sair()
    elif cad == '5':
        retorno()
```

Eu uso `while True`, que cria um *loop* infinito. A diferença para ficar chamando a função `opc` várias vezes dentro dela mesma (ou dentro de outras funções) indefinidamente é que aqui não há várias chamadas sendo empilhadas e por isso não ocorrerá o `RecursionError`. Não use recursão onde não precisa - e na maioria das vezes um *loop* simples como esse resolve.

Repare também que [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) já retorna uma string, então fazer `str(input(...))` é redundante e desnecessário.

A função `retorno` não funcionava porque você colocou o `else` dentro do `for`, ou seja, para cada elemento, ele vê se é o nome digitado, e para cada elemento que não é igual a esse nome, ele imprime a mensagem. Eu mudei para interromper o `for` (com o `break`) assim que encontrar o nome (pois se já encontrou, não faz sentido continuar o *loop*). E o `else` é do `for`, não do `if` (outras linguagens não têm esse recurso, mas o Python tem), e ele cai no `else` se o *loop* não for interrompido por um `break` (ou seja, se o nome não está na lista).

E na função `sair` eu usei `del` para apagar o elemento. Detalhe: em geral, não é uma boa ideia apagar elementos da lista no mesmo *loop* que itera sobre ela (conforme  explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/438696/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/435747/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/466780/112052)), mas neste caso específico eu removo e já interrompo o *loop* com `break`, então os problemas citados nos links já indicados não ocorrem. Também usei [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) para iterar pelos índices juntamente com os elementos da lista.

E eu mudei outra coisa: estou guardando somente os nomes nas listas, em vez de um dicionário. A menos que você vá guardar mais informações em cada registro, não há muito ganho em usar dicionários aqui.

Comment: Vlw fera. muito obrigado pelas dicas foi de grande ajuda.