# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def add_divisors(list_num):
    final_list = []
    for number in list_num:
        final_list.append([number])
    
    for sublist in final_list:
        for number in sublist:
            for x in range(1, number + 1):
                if number % x == 0:
                    sublist.extend(x)
            
    return final_list


print(add_divisors([3, 4, 6]))
```

Estou tentando fazer uma função que recebe uma lista de números, e retorna pequenas listas contendo todos os divisores do número.
Porém estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
File "<string>", line 11, in add_divisors
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: O método `extend` somente aceita objetos iteráveis como argumento e você está passando `x`, que é de tipo `int`. O problema está aí pelo que vejo.

Comment: O programa entra em loop quando quando acha um número que seja divisível por `x` pois fica auto incrementando `sublist` com o mesmo valor indefinidamente. Talvez seja melhor remover ou comentar a linha `sublist.append(x)`

Comment: Para que o for na sublist uma vez que ela retorna `final_list` ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema, como já disseram, é que está usando `extend`, que recebe um iterável e adiciona todos os elementos deste na lista. Mas você está passando um número, que não é iterável. Então deveria usar `append` para adicionar o elemento.

Só que você modifica a lista `sublist` no mesmo *loop* que itera sobre ela, e isso nunca é uma boa ideia (leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/438696/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/435747/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/466780/112052) para entender melhor).

Enfim, me parece que você está complicando o código à toa. Se quer criar uma lista contendo sub-listas, sendo que cada sub-lista contém os divisores de um número, daria para fazer assim:

```
def add_divisors(list_num):
    final_list = []
    for number in list_num:
        sublist = []
        for x in range(1, number + 1):
            if number % x == 0:
                sublist.append(x)
        final_list.append(sublist)
    return final_list

print(add_divisors([3, 4, 6])) # [[1, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 6]]
```

---

Claro que essa é a abordagem ingênua, você não precisa fazer um *loop* até o número, [pode ir até a raiz quadrada dele](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5811176). E pode começar do 2, pois todo número é divisível por 1, então para que testar o 1? Coloque-o direto na lista. O mesmo vale para o próprio número.

E para cada divisor que você encontrar, na verdade você encontrou - potencialmente - dois divisores. Por exemplo, se o número for 100 e você encontra o divisor 2, você também já encontrou o divisor 50 (resultado de 100 / 2). Então basta inserir ambos, economizando uma iteração do loop. Só precisa tomar cuidado para o caso de quadrados perfeitos, para não contar duas vezes o mesmo divisor (por exemplo, se o número for 100, não podemos usar esta lógica com o divisor 10, senão ele será contado duas vezes).

Então ficaria assim:

```
from math import sqrt

def add_divisors(list_num):
    final_list = []
    for number in list_num:
        divisores = [ 1 ] # é divisor de qualquer número
        for x in range(2, int(sqrt(number)) + 1):
            divisao, resto = divmod(number, x)
            if resto == 0:
                divisores.append(x)
                if x != divisao:
                    divisores.append(divisao)
        divisores.append(number) # todo número é divisor de si mesmo
        final_list.append(divisores)
    return final_list
```

Apesar de ter ficado "com mais linhas", ele faz menos iterações do que se fosse de 1 até o número (claro que para valores pequenos não fará tanta diferença assim, mas enfim).